# Tag synonyms: [17.10] and [ubuntu-17.10]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I just found out there's a [ubuntu-17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-17.10) tag with two questions currently.

I think it's just a synonym of [17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/17.10). I have [suggested a tag synonym](https://askubuntu.com/tags/17.10/synonyms).

Comment: I approved the tag synonym, because I see no problem with doing it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We don't seem to have tags like that for other Ubuntu release numbers. No [ubuntu-16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-16.04), for example, just [16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/16.04). Since there were only two questions tagged [ubuntu-17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-17.10), I've just retagged them to [17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/17.10).

The system will remove the tag after a while if it is not applied to any more questions. If it comes back and people start using it on multiple posts, I'd definitely support making it a synonym, but I somewhat doubt that will happen.

Comment: Great! That sounds like a far better solution. :)

Comment: Shall I now edit the question and ask people to downvote the suggested tag synonym so that it gets removed? I don't see an option to remove it myself!

Comment: @pomsky I see no need to do either. Probably it will not become a tag synonym. And I don't think it would really be a problem if it did get approved as one. If enough people with a high enough score in the [tag:17.10] voted it up as one, then maybe they know something I don't (and maybe one of them would also post here).